# Apache on Ubuntu blocking all XSS attempts

Tags: 14.04, apache2, security, www

I have a DigitalOcean droplet that I am trying to build an intentionally vulnerable lab on for my school's information security program. The problem is that Apache is blocking all sorts of malicious requests, such as cross-site scripting, file inclusion, SQL injection, stuff like that, and I need to know how to disable this. Here is an example request:

```
GET /mutillidae/index.php?page=../../../../../etc/passwd%00 HTTP/1.1
Host: ksu-labs.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: showhints=1; username=admin; uid=1; PHPSESSID=27dps71931p1dt19vkdl0thu05
Connection: close
```

What is happening is the server is resetting the connection upon reception of the request and I am getting no response. Hope you guys can help. 
Thanks in advance.

~Austin

Comment: Here's a one-line command that'll crack your system wide open: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem correctly. thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, not apache or ubuntu related, it appears that the college's firewall has some sort of terrible IPS/IDS that is blocking outbound attack attempts, easily circumvented, but nothing OS or software related, thanks anyways guys.